# MySQL - Using array within the select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

What is the correct way to do what I'm trying? Discover that the checks IN does what I need.

```
$hierarquia = implode(",", $_POST['hierarquia']);
// Show: 3,4

(
    SELECT planoDeConta FROM `financ_receita` 
    WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30'
    planoDeConta IN ($hierarquia)

) UNION ALL (

    SELECT planoDeConta FROM `financ_despesa` 
    WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30'
    planoDeConta IN ($hierarquia)

)
```

Comment: What makes you think your way is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error because you are missing a conjunction before the second condition in each query:

```
(
    SELECT planoDeConta
    FROM `financ_receita` 
    WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30' AND
          planoDeConta IN ($hierarquia)

) UNION ALL (
    SELECT planoDeConta
    FROM `financ_despesa` 
    WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30' AND
          planoDeConta IN ($hierarquia)
)
```

This should work because you are doing the variable substitution for `$hierarquia` at the "query-string" level.  It would not work if you just input the value as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The values ​​must be quoted. To do this, simply use the code below:

```
$hierarquia2 = sprintf( "'%s'", implode( "','", $_POST['hierarquia'] ) );
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: This is not how you quote values to use in SQL query. There are dedicated functions for it, depending on what sql extension are you using.